# Why uiautomator2 gets more controls than uiautomator？

Tags: android

uiautomator can not get ui-objectInfo, for example:battery icon, wifi icon..
But uiautomator can do it.why?

Who can tell me the principle..Thanks!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O88lz.png)

Comment: Earnestly ask for an answer

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.